# How to convert Dynamic URL to Static URL - So that the PHP Sends an URL to browser and .htaccess converts it and sends its back to the PHP

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite, dynamic, static, directoryindex

I am new to .htaccess, I tried googling every questions I had on .htaccess to understand. I found few tutorials, but I am couldnot understand anything.

First Question:
**What is the difference between input url and output url concerned to .htaccess**

---

**Second Question:**

PHP, In an index page i have

```
header('Location:http://example.com/index.php?p=test&c=math&t=geometry&id=100');
```

What i want on browser url is

```
http://example.com/test/math/geometry/100
```

and using htaccess I want to get the below url back to php

```
http://example.com/index.php?p=test&c=math&t=geometry&id=100
```

---

**third Question:**

if in someway, the above is possible
how can i do this
in php, in an index page

```
header('Location:http://example.com/index.php?p=test&t=geometry&id=100');
```

using .htaccess I want to get the below code on url

```
http://example.com/test/geometry/100
```

and php should get the below code from .htaccess

```
http://example.com/index.php?p=test&t=geometry&id=100
```

---

**Fourth Question:**
Please help me, I also have found the below solution and I am not able to understand what is happening in the below code.

```
RewriteEngine on
DirectoryIndex index.php

# REDIRECT Force requests for named index files to drop the index file filename, and force non-www to avoid redirect loop
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]*/)*index\.(html?|php[45]?)(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*/)*)index\.(html?|php[45]?)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+)/([^\.]+)\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([^.]+)\.php$ http://example.com/$1/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^\.]+)\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([^.]+)\.php$ http://example.com/$1/$2/$3 [R=301,L]

# REDIRECT www to non-wwww
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# REWRITE url to filepath
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([^/.]+)$ /$1/$2.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([^/.]+)$ /$1/$2/$3.php [L]
```

Thanks in advance